# Argument of type x is not assignable to parameter of type '(x) => ObservableInput<{}>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

hopefully someone can shed some light on this

Working with ngrx and trying to use multiple switchMaps to call some action classes.

My Actions:

```
export class BlogAddedAction implements Action {

    readonly type = BLOG_ADDED_ACTION;

    constructor(public payload:any) {

    }

}
export class CrudSucessAction implements Action {

    readonly type = CRUD_SUCCESS_ACTION;

    constructor(public payload:any) {

    }
}

export class BlogAddedToDBAction implements Action {

    readonly type = BLOG_ADDED_TO_DB_ACTION;

    constructor(public payload:any) {

    }
}
```

effects.ts:

```
  @Effect() addBlog$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
  .ofType<BlogAddedAction>(BLOG_ADDED_ACTION)
    .switchMap(action =>  {
        console.log(action)
    return this.blogService.addBlog(action.payload.blog)
    })
    .switchMap((action)=>new BlogAddedToDBAction(action))
    .map((action)=>new CrudSucessAction(action))
}
```

But I'm getting the Typescript error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(action: Blog) => BlogAddedToDBAction' is not 
assignable to parameter of type '(value: Blog, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.Type 'BlogAddedToDBAction' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
Type 'BlogAddedToDBAction' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.Property 'length' is missing in type 'BlogAddedToDBAction'.
```

Tried using map instead of second switchMap but `BlogAddedToDBAction` doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchMap` should be used when you want to emit an Observable that you can cancel -- in this case it's the `addBlog` http request. In this case you most likely want `mergeMap` instead since if you try to add a blog before the previous blog has finished being added it will get canceled. See: https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524

`switchMap` requires an Observable-compatible value to be emitted, so you can't return a plain object like `BlogAddedToDBAction`. Instead you could do `of(new BlogAddedToDBAction(action))` since `of` will create an Observable that emits that object -- *however* this may not be what you want.

The `Effect` is a single Observable stream that emits actions. Your stream is only emitting the `CrudSuccessAction`.

It seems like you probably want to emit both actions. For this, you can use `merge`. Then the Effect Observable will emit each action in sequence. I would write it like this:

```
@Effect() addBlog$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<BlogAddedAction>(BLOG_ADDED_ACTION),
  mergeMap(action =>  {
    console.log(action)
    return this.blogService.addBlog(action.payload.blog).pipe(
      mergeMap(action => [new BlogAddedToDBAction(action), new CrudSucessAction(action)]),
      catchError(() => of(new CrudErrorAction())
  });
```

`mergeMap` with an array will emit each value of the array. You can confirm this using a simple test:

```
of(1).pipe(mergeMap(() => [1, 2])).subscribe(console.log); // logs 1, then 2
```

Comment: Thanks for that it worked, looks like I have to do some more reading up on rxjs too